# Magento: how much RAM does database consume?

Tags: mysql, magento

I have a Magento ecommerce.
The tables in my database take up +/- 500 MB on disk.(I clean log tables every week).
With htop, I see that mysqld uses 330M of resource. My site haven't got lot of traffic (5/10 users simultaneously).
In total, the site take up +/- 1600 MB on the server.
It's a normal value?

Answer (score 0):

I have a webstore with around 1.200 products and pictures (in development).
It uses 406mb of webspace @ the hosting company. 
The database is 95mb, so 500mb is pretty big.

Is it possible that (if you use images in your webstore) all images are saved into the database tables instead of "linked to" by Magento?

Comment: My store is 3 years old. For instance, the table "customer_address_entity_varchar" require 62 MB.. I haven't images into the database.